# Unable to modify any sonar settings

Tags: sonarqube, logback

Recently we moved from our old Sonar instance (2.x) to a recent 4.1 SonarQube version. During the migration we did a full port of the database with the migration of all data to latest 4.x format.

The migration was successful and all the data was available at our new server but, when trying to configure anything inside Sonar interface I detected that Sonar is not saving anything, it reloads the website with the old settings.

We are using the CAS plugin (the forked version that is compatible) and we are able to login into the system but unable to save any data. I have tried to have a look at log files but neither access nor sonar log give any information (some 404 but no exception to track). I have also tried to raise the log level but logback.xml is ignoring my settings...

I have run out of ideas (filesystem permissions... checked, database permissions... checked, logs... checked) and unable to find new information. Anyone knows how to increment log level on the new Sonar? Anyone has faced those problems?

Thanks

Comment: It looks that the sonar CAS plugin is the responsible of that behavior. Having removed the plugin I am able to modify settings again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SonarQube CAS plugin is deprecated since SonarQube 3.3, as you can read on [the documentation page](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/CAS+Plugin).

So this plugin will probably not behave correctly with latest versions of SonarQube.

Comment: I knew about that, that's why I was trying a forked version that said that was compatible with SonarQube 3.7+. The plugin allows authentication successfully but seems to fail at some place... There is any way to increase verbosity?